# Space between hr and h2 tag

Tags: html, css

I would like that my between the hr and h1 tag, there was not so much space between. I tried to set margin, padding but none of this worked on the h2 tag, but works fine on h1 tag. Does anybody knows how I can do that?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="adresse">
   <h2>Fredag d.10 november 2016</h2><hr />
   <h1>Hotel, Copenhagen</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
hr {
    width: 77%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
 .adresse h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

.adresse h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3594cb;
}
```

Comment: can you please add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: remove the `float: left;` in the `hr` selector. You don't need that. And will cause more problems, most of them related with your issue

Comment: Why do you need to use an `<hr>` tag at all? - You can apply a border to an `<h2>` - also in your HTML your `<h1>` is below your `<h2>` these should be the other way around you want your most important one first ie `<h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So below in your css-file is given a different value margin and padding for h1 and h2. Check this. You can also set the line spacing using the Line-height.

```
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0;
-webkit-margin-after: 0;
```

H tags have before and after margins. So making them 0 as above erases the gap.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

To make the gap between `hr` and `h1` smaller add `line-height:15px;` or other value of pixels in `h1`.

```css
hr {
    width: 77%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
 .adresse h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
   line-height:15px;
}

.adresse h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3594cb;
}
```

```html
<div class="adresse">
   <h2>Fredag d.10 november 2016</h2><hr />
   <h1>Hotel, Copenhagen</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
    width: 77%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
 .adresse h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
   margin-top: 20px;
}

.adresse h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3594cb;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="adresse">
   <h2>Fredag d.10 november 2016</h2><hr />
   <br><h1>Hotel, Copenhagen</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   hr {
        width: 100%;
        
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
     .adresse h1{
        
        margin: 0px;
      
    }

    .adresse h2 {
       
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #3594cb;
      
    }
```

```html
 


    <div class="adresse">
       <h2>Fredag d.10 november 2016</h2><hr />
       <h1>Hotel, Copenhagen</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
 h1,h2{
          margin:0 !important;
          padding:0 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to achieved something like this

```css
hr {
    width: 77%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
 .adresse h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

.adresse h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3594cb;
  padding: 40px;
    margin: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adresse">
   <h2>Fredag d.10 november 2016</h2><hr />
   <h1>Hotel, Copenhagen</h1>
</div>
```